# CSS messing gridview button?

Tags: asp.net, css

For some weird reason all the buttons I place inside any gridview appear as really shrunk (like in pic below) even though the gridview is default and has no CSS attached to it.

Could it be some other CSS as I have way too many code to list it here (downloaded free template)?

What could the problem be? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: a global definition of the `input` inside the css is your issue. Open the browser tools to locate this settings and change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inheriting some style from parent or global input css file. To know where exactly the problem is use IE Developer tool...Select the button in the developer tool and see styles that are not crossed out on the right side of the developer tool

Comment: this css was causing the mistake: * { padding:0;}
Thanks for your help